# how to set header for dat to be stored in database in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, post, response-headers

I write post method to insert to mongodb:

```
const express = require("express");
const app=express();
const _route=require('./router/router.js')
require('dotenv').config();
require('./Database/config.js');
const port_=process.env.PORT|| 8080;
const product=require('./model/model.js');
const { db } = require("./model/model.js");
app.use('/insert',async(req,res)=>{
    const newProduct=new product({
        _id:57,
        name:'GLX MAD',
        description:'Newest iranian phone'
    });
    try{
        await newProduct.save(); 
         res.json(newProduct);
        res.send('inserted')
    }
    catch(err){
        res.send(err);
    }
    });

    app.get('/:id',async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const get=await product.findById(req.params.id);
            res.json(get);
        }
        catch(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
    });
    app.get('/',async(req,res)=>{
        try{
            const get= await product.find();
            res.json(get);
        }
        catch(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
    })
app.listen(port_,'localhost',()=>{ console.log(`App run on port ${port_}`)});
```

the model is as follow:

```
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const { stringify } = require("nodemon/lib/utils");
require('../Database/config');

const _product=mongoose.Schema({
    _id:{
        type:Number,
        require:true
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    description:{
        type:String,
        require:false
    }
});
```

config of database is as follow:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const port_=process.env.PORT|| 8080;
const connectionString=`mongodb://localhost:27017/`;


mongoose.connect(connectionString,{
    dbname:'Market',
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true
},err=>{
    err?console.log('Connection fail '+ err):console.log('Connect success.')
});
```

when I use post method e.g:`localhost:3000/insert` the data insert to database and then get following error and can not perform next operation such as get all data or get specific data:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

how to set header for the data to be stored to database?
what is this header? why

Answer (score 0):

Because of you return a json and you continue send a text

```
res.json(newProduct);
res.send('inserted')
```

just remove the second line `res.send('inserted')`

---

ref: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send